# How to access properties of object inside list and list object is inside hashmap using freemarker?

Tags: templates, hashmap, javabeans, freemarker

I'm trying to access the properties of my object. but i'm this error .

```
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing
interestRate  [in template "interestRate" at line 2, column 8]
```

In my code i'm creating a list of my pojoclass objects and mapping this list with hasmap.

```
List<InterestRateVO> list = new ArrayList<InterestRateVO>();
Map<String,List<InterestRateVO>> interestRate = new HashMap<String,List<InterestRateVO>> ();
list.add(interestRateVO);
interestRate.put(tableData[1],list);
```

tableData is a dynamic value i'm getting from response. here is my hashmap object value

```
{3Y    =[com.test.ft.vo.InterestRateVO@18923c7, com.test.ft.vo.InterestRateVO@8c1c27, com.test.ft.vo.InterestRateVO@8c520e], 5Y    =[com.test.ft.vo.InterestRateVO@5f48b4, com.test.ft.vo.InterestRateVO@19e3e55, com.test.ft.vo.InterestRateVO@e7bcd]}
```

and here is my pojoclass

```
public class InterestRateVO {


    private String currency;
    private String rate;
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }
    public void setRate(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

}
```

and freemarker template i'm using this code

```
<#list interestRate?keys as inter>
  ${inter} = ${interestRate[inter].currency} 
</#list>
```

Comment: Where do you put the `interestRate` map itself into the data-model (aka. template context)?

Comment: Are you sending `interestRate` to the view?